# Ember.Select selected value not binding to object

Tags: ember.js

Ok folks, this is really starting to wind me up.  I'm assuming I'm doing something dumb or missing something but I cannot seem to get a select list to bind the selected value to the object.  All I'm trying to do is create some cascading drop down lists, like you see in sites like auto trader.

```
App.CarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    selectedCarMake: null,

    availableCarMakes: Em.computed(function () {
        return this.store.find("carMake"); // => GET /carMake
    }).cacheable(),

    availableCarModels: Em.computed(function () {
        var make = this.get('selectedCarMake');
        // the line below returns the id and not an object
        console.log(make);
        if (make === undefined || make === null)
            return [];
        return make.get('carModels');
    }).property('selectedCarMake'),
});
```

these are my models

```
App.CarMake= DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    carModels: DS.hasMany('carModel', { async: true })
});

App.CarModel= DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and this is my html markup

```
         <td>
                {{view Ember.Select
                            contentBinding="availableCarMakes"
                            optionLabelPath="content.name"
                            optionValuePath="content.id"
                            valueBinding="selectedCarMake"
                            prompt="Please Select..."
                }}
            </td>
```

So the first drop down list (shown above) does populate but when you select a value and it calls availableModels to bind the second drop down list, it bombs because selectedCarMake is an id and not an object.  Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as you said, you're binding the user's selection to an object, use `selection=selectedCarMake` instead of `valueBinding='selectedCarMake'`. Value just binds the value of each `<option>` (not the entire object bound to the Ember option) to whatever property your specify. See the [Em.Select docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#property_selection) for more info.